# Declaring class member with deduced type

Tags: c++

I have a code that uses type deduction like this:

```
template <typename... Ttypes>
Tuple<Ttypes...> makeTuple(Ttypes... args) {
   Tuple<Ttypes...> result;
   fillTuple<0>(result, args...);
   return result;
}
```

I want to encapsulate the result to a class which is not a class template. The only way, and this is reasonable, is to have it as a `static const` member like this:

```
struct A {
    static const auto t = makeTuple(1,2,3,'c');
};
```

and I get: `error: in-class initializer for static data member of type 'const Tuple<int, int, int, char>' requires 'constexpr' specifier static const auto tuple = makeTuple(1,2,3,'c');`.

If I use

```
struct A {
    static const auto constexpr t = makeTuple(1,2,3,'c');
};
```

I get `error: constexpr variable 'tuple' must be initialized by a constant expression`.

Moreover, using `constexpr` is not good for me, because I' like to use non-literal types in a tuple.

Compiler Clang with -std=c++14.

Is there a way to get what I want?

Comment: @walnut: I would say partially, as deduction part is missing.

Answer (score 2):

Something along these lines, perhaps:

```
struct A {
    using TupleType = decltype(makeTuple(1,2,3,'c'));
    static const TupleType  t;
};

// In a .cpp file
const A::TupleType A::t = makeTuple(1,2,3,'c');
```

---

Somewhat more elaborate, but avoids some repetition:

```
struct A {
    static auto MakeMyTuple() { return makeTuple(1,2,3,'c'); }
    using TupleType = decltype(MakeMyTuple());
    static const TupleType t;
};

// In a .cpp file
const A::TupleType A::t = A::MakeMyTuple();
```

This way, arguments to `makeTuple` are all in one place.

Comment: I am trying the case without repetitions (the second one) - looks fine, but doesn't work: `error: function 'MakeMyTuple' with deduced return type cannot be used before it is defined` on the line `using TupleType = decltype(MakeMyTuple());`

Comment: OK, after moving `MakeMyTuple` to a baseclass and removing `const` qualifier, I got working solution like this:

`struct TupledBase
{
    static auto MakeMyTuple() { return makeTuple(1, 2, 3, 'c'); }
};
  
struct Tupled: TupledBase
{   
    using TupleType = decltype (MakeMyTuple());
    static TupleType t;
};
  
Tupled::TupleType Tupled::t = Tupled::MakeMyTuple();`

Comment: in order to have `static const TupleType t` - can add `const` before `decltype`, like: `using TupleType = const decltype(MakeMyTuple());`

Comment: Or even, you might do: `struct A {
    static const auto& t() { static const auto instance = std::make_tuple(1,2,3,'c'); return instance; }
};
` with only extra parent at usage.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to accomplish this without declaring the member static.
auto is useful for type deduction when it is also being initialized. If declaration is needed prior to initialization you can use decltype instead.

GeeksForGeeks has a good introduction to decltype.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/type-inference-in-c-auto-and-decltype/

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

template<typename... Types>
tuple<Types...> makeTuple(Types... types)
{
    return tuple<Types...>();
}


//I'm using these two functions just to show 
//that non constexpr functions can be used to determine type
int generateInt()
{
    return 1;
}

char generateChar()
{
    return 'a';
}

struct A
{
    decltype(makeTuple(generateInt(), generateChar())) t;

    A() : t(makeTuple(1, 'a'))
    {

    }
};

int main()
{
    A a;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Like OP said, OP cannot use a constexpr function since he is using C++14.

Comment: OP doesn't want to use constexpr in the wrapper class which is not necessary. C++14 support constexpr as well and this will still compile without constexpr in the makeTuple.

Comment: Also, the variable `t` is not marked `static const` which is what OP wants.

Comment: "I want to encapsulate the result to a class which is not a class template. The only way, and this is reasonable, is to have it as a static const member like this". Sounds like OP was under the impression that a static was necessary. Either way, it can be modified to be static. Up to OP.

Comment: Yes, `static const` is not requirement, and it's useful to know that this is also an option. Thank you!

Comment: @KevinBright I think your solution is working, but requires for some duplications... The second option in Igor Tandetnik answer is more ocnvenient one I think.. Thanks anyway!